# Create dynamic components with different location in logical component tree

Tags: angular

I'm looking to to build a component that uses Angular's `componentFactoryResolver` and `componentFactory` to dynamically inject a component onto the DOM but uses a passed in viewContainerRef to determine what is available for injection.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component-loader',
  template: ``
})
export class MyComponentLoader implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private componentLoaderService: ComponentLoaderService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.componentLoaderService.loadComponent.pipe(
        tap((component, componentViewContainerRef) => this.loadComponent(component, componentViewContainerRef))
      ).subscribe();
  }

  loadComponent(component, callerViewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();

    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```

How do I load the component within the `my-component-loader` location, with the logical location from `callerViewContainerRef` so that the created component has the DI tree available for `callerViewContainerRef`.

In short this would be similar in manner to Material's MatDialog.

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/dialog/dialog-config.ts

Is there a simpler way to handle with without replicating Angular CDK portal logic?

** EDIT **

Is this as simple as passing in the callerViewContainerRef's injector?

```
this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory, 0 , callerViewContainerRef.injector);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this as simple as passing in the callerViewContainerRef's injector?

I think this is correct. Here's a separate example of mine that led me to a better understanding.

#### app.tokens.ts

```js
export const FooToken = new InjectionToken('foo');
```

#### app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
 /* ... */
 providers: [
  {
   provide: FooToken,
   useValue: { message: 'default foo value' }
  }
 ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ng-container #vcr></ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('vcr', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
  vcr: ViewContainerRef;

  ngAfterViewInit () {
    const compFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(FooComp);

    const inj = Injector.create({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: FooToken,
          useValue: { message: 'this is just a foo message from a dynamic injector!' }
        }
      ]
    })

    this.vcr.createComponent(compFactory, 0, inj); 
  }
}
```

#### foo.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: `Foo!!`
})
export class FooComp {
  constructor (@Inject(FooToken) private fooToken) {
    console.log('[FOO]', this.fooToken)
  }
}
```

If you run the code as it is, you should see `{ message: 'this is just a foo message from a dynamic injector!' }` inside Foo's constructor.

However, if you create the component without specifying a **custom injector**

```js
this.vcr.createComponent(compFactory);
```

you should see this: `{ message: 'default foo value' }`

You can find the above idea in my [`playground`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/di-tips?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).